# Tensorflow add a new op, could not import from python

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I did as shown in the tensorflow document: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/adding_an_op/#attrs

1. get the source code from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
2. add a `zero_out.cc` file under `tensorflow/core/user_ops/`
3. add a `BUILD` file under `tensorflow/core/user_ops/`
4. run in terminal:   `$ bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/core/user_ops:zero_out.so`

> INFO: Found 1 target...
>   Target //tensorflow/core/user_ops:zero_out.so up-to-date:
>   bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/zero_out.so
>   INFO: Elapsed time: 0.125s, Critical Path: 0.00s

But when I run the following code in python, error comes:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
>>> zero_out_module = tf.load_op_library('zero_out.so')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/yc/tfenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 64, in load_op_library
    None, None, error_msg, error_code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: zero_out.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Seems like you're not using the anaconda build. The easiest way is to install it from there. But try to install tensorflow 0.11 since 0.12 has some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Bazel would generate the op library into the `bazel-bin` folder.

As you used bazel to build ot, you should try to load it from there:

```
zero_out_module = tf.load_op_library('bazel-bin/tensorflow/user_ops/zero_out.so')
```